# How to parameterized array with activerecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel, parameterized

Activerecord generates parameterized queries for basic types, but, it does parametrize array types.

E.g.

```
Article.where(id: 1) 
# generates
# SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
```

But,

```
Article.where(id: [1,2])
# generates
# SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" IN (1, 2)
# rather than
# SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" IN ($1, $2)
  [["id", 1], ["id", 2],]
```

Is it possible to restructure the query or use Arel to generate parametrized query for IN clauses?

Comment: What rails version? For it generate non-param version in both cases in 4.1? https://gist.github.com/gaurish/be9d29d09162e2213611

Comment: I tried with latest rails version. You won't see the parameter query with it to_sql because it replaces binding parameters with values. Try enabling activerecord logging with `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` in rails console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was not able to find something out of box, so, I implemented specialized versions of where operators which generates parameterized queries for `<`, `>`, `in` and raw arel conditions, and it should be easy to add support for more operators if needed..

https://github.com/faisalmansoor/activerecord-extensions

```
Post.where_gt(:likes, 10).to_a
# will generate
# SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts"."likes" > ?)
# [["likes", 10]]

Post.where_lt(:likes, 10).to_a
# will generate
# SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts"."likes" < ?)
# [["likes", 10]]

Post.where_in(:likes, [2,3,4]).pluck(:title).to_a
# will generate
# SELECT "posts"."title" FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."likes" IN (?, ?, ?)
# [["likes", 2], ["likes", 3], ["likes", 4]]


clause = Post.arel_table[:title].
  eq(Arel::Nodes::BindParam.new).
  or(Post.arel_table[:likes].gt(Arel::Nodes::BindParam.new))

Post.where_with_bind(clause, {title: 'Good Title', likes: 10}).to_a

# will generate
# SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts"."title" = ? OR "posts"."likes" > ?)
# [["title", "Good Title"], ["likes", 10]]
```